# Button Event-listener is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm following a tutorial and I made a button to show some content. However this button doesn't work and I'm at my wits end unable to figure out what could be causing this.

Can someone show why this doesn't work?

```js
const users = document.querySelector('#user');
const getUsers = document.getElementById('getUsers');
getUsers.addEventListener('click', loadUsers);
var loadUsers = () => {
  console.log('hello button clicked')
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users', true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      let gusers = this.responseText
      console.log(gusers);
    }
  }
  xhr.send()
}
console.log(getUsers)
```

```html
<h1>USER</h1>
<button id="getUsers">Get Users</button>
<div id="users"></div>
```

Comment: move the `.addEventListener(...)` after `var loadUsers` implementation

Comment: Arrow functions aren't hoisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of your variable declarations matters in this scenario due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) - move the `loadUsers` definition above the call.

> JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations. If a
>   variable is declared and initialized after using it, the value will be
>   undefined.

The block-quote above from MDN explains why function declarations can be defined *after* they are called (reading code from top-to-bottom), but variables that are initialized after they are used would have a value of `undefined`.

```js
const users = document.querySelector('#user');
const getUsers = document.getElementById('getUsers');
const loadUsers = () => {
  console.log('Load users..');
}

getUsers.addEventListener('click', loadUsers);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>USER</h1>
  <button id="getUsers">Get Users</button>
  <div id="users"></div>
</body>
```

Or you could keep the function at the bottom but use a function declaration which will be hoisted:

```js
const users = document.querySelector('#user');
const getUsers = document.getElementById('getUsers');

getUsers.addEventListener('click', loadUsers);

function loadUsers() {
  console.log('Load users..');
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>USER</h1>
  <button id="getUsers">Get Users</button>
  <div id="users"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Functions definitions are hoisted not variables. Got it thanks!

Comment: @Weezy Great! Glad it helped

Comment: @Weezy - just to clarify - variable declarations ARE hoisted, just not the initialization of the variable which is why you will get a value of `undefined` for those variables instead of your code throwing a `ReferenceError`

Comment: @Weezy - last thing. It's good to read up on the differences between `var` and `let`, `const` when it comes to how they are hoisted: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/

Comment: Thank you sir. I will. That is why I was careful not to use the word declaration instead.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answer have a look at your code that I have refactored below. Hope this helps.

```js
// Get Elements
const usersList = document.querySelector('#usersList');
const usersBtn = document.querySelector('#usersBtn');

// Bind listener to usersButton
usersBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 // XHR Request function
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET','https://api.github.com/users')
  xhr.send()
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      // Convert the response to JSON and assign it to data
      const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      // Loop throug through data
      for(let i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
       // Create LI element and append the user name
       const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        usersList.appendChild(listItem).innerHTML = data[i].login
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>USERS</h1>
<button id="usersBtn">Get Users</button>
<ul id="usersList"></ul>
```

Comment: Only problem I see with this is this line: `const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` - this assumes the data in `responseText` will be JSON format. Wouldn't work as expected if the `responseText` is XML, HTML, plain text, etc.